# Merge array of data from API

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting, csv

Firstly, I have a reporting system where I pull across CSV data, which comes back in a pretty bad state.

The way the data is pulled back is via:

```
$data = explode("\t", $site);
$sID = $data[1];
$sCol = $data[2];
```

and so on.

I can use these variables further down when echoing and not a problem.

My real problem is in the data above, I get several `$sID` back in this format:

```
20390    Red
20390    Blue
20390    Green
20390    White
20391    Blue
20391    Yellow
20391    Green
20391    White
```

I'd like to combine all the data onto a single row, such as:

```
20390  Red, Blue, Green, White
```

Something similar to `array_merge` would be ideal, however not sure what function can duplicate this.

Comment: Try:

implode(', ',$sID);

Comment: @Codew That doesn't seem to give me anything.

Comment: provide the content of `$site` so that we can see how it looks like prior the explode. So far, I'm assuming that `$site` only has these contents `"20390\tRed"` which tells me youre looping this in some type of iteration to get that list.. ? if thats the case where is `$site` coming from?

Comment: The data that comes across from $site looks like

`SID     COLOR      DATE            AMT      FEE

20390    Red       2015-02-16     0.55      0.15
20390    Blue      2015-02-16     0.45      0.35
20390    Green     2015-02-16     1.55      1.15
20390    White     2015-02-16     0.25      0.05
20391    Blue      2015-02-16     1.55      1.15
20391    Yellow    2015-02-16     0.65      0.10
20391    Green     2015-02-16     0.35      0.25
20391    White     2015-02-16     0.55      0.15  `

I simply explode and then use the positions from the data ($data[1] etc) to echo out the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in your case, this is what I would do:

```
$data = explode("\t", $site[0]);

$final = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if ($row != 0) {
        $info = explode(" ", $row);
        if (isset($final[$info[0]])) {
            array_push($final[$info[0]], "$info[1], $info[2], $info[3], $info[3]");
        } else {
            $final[$info[0]] = array();
            array_push($final[$info[0]], "$info[1], $info[2], $info[3], $info[3]");
        }
    }
}
var_dump($final);
```

Comment: Yarp this is how to do it

Comment: This solved my issue with a couple of changes, thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
   $data = explode("\t", $site);
   $s[$data[1]] = array_key_exists($data[1], $s)?($s[$data[1]].', '.$data[2]):$data[2];
foreach($s as $k => $val){
  $sID = $k;
  $sCol = $val;
}
```